# Sunspot Solr Rails - hidden fields scoping and associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, solr, sunspot-solr

I would like to use hidden field parameters(colour_id) to refine my search to fabrics associated with particular Colours.

Fabrics have many Colours, Suppliers and Categories

However I would like the paramers from hidden fields in my search form (colour_ids) to filter the fabrics, so that only fabrics associated with those colours are searched against.

From what I gather the best way of doing this would be to add scopes to my search, and pass the parameters of these hidden fields to the scope to narrow the search results to only fabrics that are associated with those colours.

My fabric model looks like this

```
class Fabric < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fabric_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :fabric_categories
  has_many :suppliers, :through => :fabric_suppliers
  has_many :fabric_suppliers
  has_many :colours, :through => :fabric_colours
  has_many :fabric_colours


  # solr search method
  searchable do
  text :name, :boost => 5
  text :description
  text :categories do
    categories.map(&:name)
  end
  text :suppliers, :boost => 2 do
   suppliers.map(&:name)
   end
  end
```

my controller

```
  class FabricsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = Fabric.search do
    fulltext params[:search]

     #scoped assets
     @fabrics = @search.results
```

and my view

```
  <%= form_tag fabrics_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search'  do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'query', id: "auto_complete", :placeholder => '', :autocomplete => "off" %>
    <div id="colour_ids">
      <%= hidden_field_tag :colour_1 %>
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'btn', :id => 'search_button' %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add category_ids to the index by including it in your `searchable` block:

```
searchable do
  ...
  integer :colour_ids, :multiple => true do
    colours.map(&:id)
  end
end
```

You will need to reindex after doing this.

Then in your query you need to include the condition in `FabricsController#index` something like this:

```
@search = Fabric.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  with :colour_ids, params[:colour_1]
end
```